# was loaded over an insecure connection on html Error

Tags: javascript, html

I was caught in an error on html
It happens when you download an image

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqFGh.png)

this image is my error code

```js
function downloadBase64File(contentBase64, fileName) {
    const linkSource = `data:image/png;base64,${contentBase64}`;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.target = '_self';
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

and i use downloadFunction code in my html

what is this error? and how i fix?

Comment: how i use https? Isn't it already applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this writing method, it may help you. If it helps, please give me a good

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function downloadBase64File(contentBase64, fileName) { 
    const linkSource = 'data:image/png;base64,' + contentBase64; // 将链接源放入引号中
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a'); 
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.href = linkSource; 
    downloadLink.target = '_self'; 
    downloadLink.download = fileName; 
    downloadLink.click(); 
}
        const contentBase64 = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAJsAmwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAQIDBAYHAAj/xAA7EAACAQMCAwYDBgQFBQAAAAABAgMABBEFIRIxQQYTIlFhcTKBoQcUI0JSkTNysdEkQ8Hh8BViksLx/8QAGQEAAgMBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQQCAwUA/8QAJBEAAgIBBAICAwEAAAAAAAAAAAECEQMEEiExIkETUSMyMxT/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AOjhaeFpQKeBS4weUYp4FeAqRVogbEVajvLu2sbdp7ydIYl5s5/5mnXVxHZ27zS/CozjqfQetc81bVL+5uBcpwCYqWVpAGS2X9S52XrlzueS0QGgu+1xRS1no19NGOUsiiFW9Rxb/Sqlh9oenSzdxfRNZy5x+IwK/vXL2ll1e/ZtT1aX7txHiuHZvH/KvIDy2FB75baOUraSMyA4BJ5+tTUL9lTnR9I2V/a6hCJbOdJUzjKsDg1a4ds18y2l9c2rcVtczQNnOYpCp+lbHQu3Wo2Tobu+nnQcxIeM/XcfI1zxtdBjkTO0cNNIrMaN2703UZIongubcvsHdQVz7g7VrF4XAKnIPWq6J2Q8JpOGpiuKQijQbISKTFS8NIVoUdZCRScNTEU0igEixSYqXhpMVwRqinikAp4ogHAU9dqQU8YxucUSLMv2pu2kuEsoAGYEYXPNj0/b/XyrBdr7yztrP/p9rOJZJXJuJxnJxz/fYAcgKKdstUcazLbWcqxyMj967HAQE4PPrgc/I/vzW8ZXeUpxHxfqLZA9Tv51KMbdkZypUiC+vXnIVVCRrsqLsAKqBzUkMM11KI4ULuegHIetH7Dsq8vCZ5uEnmF6VOeWEO2Qx4MmX9UZ5WqaKQqc1sF7HW7DCzMD1qdew8DrgTMG/Uap/wBeMvehygLQdSe1uxKHAAwWDE4OOQruXZTUhqWj21xjBkXkefOuHax2Y1LSg0mDPb9XjX4fcUd7E9sI9NuoYr53EJXhZwM8PLh2z79OtWOpq4lVSx+MzuHDScNQ6beQ39rHcW8qyxuMq6nIIqzioh6IuGkK1KcDnULyqPX2oBXJ7FMYqOtMLu/wjHvSd1xfGc0LJUNaUcl3pnFJ5VOECjYV6hQRtPFNqRRRQBwpLmTubaST9Kk/sKctQ6rvpd2FO/cPj/xNEBwDtdqXFrl+ieIrJwByT05/WhGk29xeXxihTiyp4jnYCo7uXv764nY5DyM2fck1pOzxi0vQpNQlVu9nJxjmQOQqyctkeCGOHyT56JtGW1tojbpGsU35mb8x/r8qO2ltJzLPvy4cCsXLLfalM0kcZXi6YxUlvJqtk4xJIB5HcUlkw7ubNLDn2cKPB0BImBx3si+65qZBKp/jbeqUO0zUZJrdRNlZCo2bbNQ6vrp0zBCNIxHIHYUootypDjmlHc+jRB2OONVI6kbg/KsD207OJZs+p6cmIOcsa/kP6h6Vdte3ZaQC6ssJ5q+9HoNUstVgdYmyrqVKMOYxypmHyYXYnN486opfY/2kEF02i3TnExaSAk7A43X57musNMzbRj96+YbmWTS7yWW0Yxy2shaNvIqcj+lfT0T97BHLgDjQNj3GadkvZmR+mRlXb4228qURoOlPNNJqJYeNJSFieQppDGhYUKWA570zjHlThH50vAK6wjRUimo6kSgBkiim3SF7SZV5lGAHyp6VJtw78qkiLPlWUGKLgccLrkN/vXVo9Kisez2nwzxhphGCEI5MdzWD7WWSDtnqFnCCFbUCir/O/wDTeuodpkne4/w5WMA4Vv0+tQ1Uqii/Qx8mzLXq2toeGa4jjl6pxAY9KqxXKFuEsrjO2N6rdodHlktIYIFiaSNiXmaQDvCep65qHR9JnV0Z2yVyH4Rs2fWlnGGzdu5H1PI57dvBrrO0E8OUUcPtQzUoIg7d/ggedanR4jDZovDkjn60E7TaVJe20n3duByc5x06iqIrkuk+GqA9tpNnqPgHAvqKfF2eNjeIFkbgO6kPis/Y6BevqqNL/CD5bhk8QHzIrc6RZX6O0N4RLbg8ULF8ug8m86Ym9qpSsWilN3KNHL9fHd314koxhn4h519MabxjS7MSEs4t4+JvM8IzXz59pNstrq7lRjvoCx9+VfRcDBoIiowDGpHtinE90EzMlHbkaE4Sa93YG5NVtS1Sx02Iy6heQ2yAZJkcD6VjdT+1HRrdCdPguL5slQeExKT7tv8ASohN0eEcqiuLmC2iMlzNHDGBu8jBQPma5Pq3bztHObZoVisrW4Hh7peJhvvuf7UJvNIvrjUi+o3ctyPCwaVi2Y2671Dcl2SUWzomq/aHoNhHm3klvmJwBbKCM+5IFCF+0a8nHe2umQdy3w95PhvntWNstDWDVJtOvWIVv4b+vMGihstPBxPGvejZsEjeoyyJE4wb7OvDnTwwHM71EilviP7VOiAVYitjlZm+Bc08IW+I0oGKdxKBzooizlXa/ToJPtN0sQoCCY3n9CCTn6CtHq7qJCNjUWtwqe29tPGG/gePA67Af1NNvgeIt5mlc+S+DS0+NRp/YKmhSRieAftUtjAkkoUABRzPlXrl+AEig1/c3Z0y4js37qaUjD+VKLsfrg04v4o5uFARGOlPeSOTMibg8/SsXYC7itYoLid5p1XxSMc71J2aOpW893aXcrzRuxaMtzUe9WU6fJDb1x2ak2qM3GI1Jq9AVC4wB50Osp2YAMetXiRzPOgiMkc8+1C2EmsWG3EJInXflzG31q1qvartXqFvGxnNrBIGAjtk4N1OCM8/rRLtLYHUdQs1YbIdm8jnP/rXrtHCzw90OGGbjBx0cf3pqOaopCGTB5tv2UdG0eOHVHuLsd8kqhmLb8aOM5OfI5pb7SLKN54FThEi5i2+F1/uKI6YJbhIyfgjBhb25iimq20ElvbvjEikZ9x/tVXyS3B2RozLFbnRljVOI27d6MdBjxD61PaSyXECSEEpbjhfffum6/I/Sp4lhsNTYLhoZN+HzVuYqC0uI9OupogAyKSpU/mQ0G7DRDrmnXH3cXAbLRsELdR5UlsLe4gSWdgJWHiB86LEzvZSRN8S/hvnfiH5W/bFZiUESMCSpB5UU/RFx9nbQ6LzO9OE2dlFV41Bxjeor3VdO0xOK/vYIB0DuMn2HM02uhVovjjbmcVKkfnvWN1vt7b6eYYrOwubqWc4jLDu05gdd+vlQW87Q9ptRTu1uIdPLozBLdPEo3Ayxzvt0xXbkjtrfCNVqvCmvYK4LBCvyB3qpdrlGoLo8Hd6vdtLd3FzwyoiGWUvhgPEd6PXI4vD5mk8i5ZoYnwgDPEZDjpTPu2E4dgB+Y8qsa3dLYW4KJxyE7KOtZi8bVdRXiuW+6wdI1OW+fSqowtjcXfAYaJQyshVxncg8qJwqAC6FWXqRWGFkVyF1EgfmBFE9Osp4sy2GpkSAfDIPC3vVnxr7Jyg6NSIl4uNDjNTLnrQPTNSuzcGG/gWI9GjbKn2o1xDBwah0VcktqiG5EzgcKMN/Kq+sNHDPIOEYuIiufUbiqsNxLJqhtg2ISoJ888v9RRvVYoSkMpHhUg+2djUl0LZX5GY0y7CTNCg8M67e/8AzNaCO1F3C4fZmUMvv1oCFit78tGR+HJxL7c60Ulwkn4kHJgGHtXEH2ZTVNOKRd/G28b8JHof96hvYY3t7XUFIyPwpV/oaM6pbTw94gJIbce1Z21WSaSWyc8HeggejdKKONDDcQ/doyzAMoEUn8p+E/I7fOqV3bQNcOWibizviqOj5kl7m6GBvFIPL/m1H+8ig/CuFJkTwk45+tRkq6CmA9c1PXrmGMPqrQNK6R93beAZJyd+ew9agt4rW47Q8CL3q21ukXE25ZuLiYnz5fWkuIlXXbOOWTKQxtO+TyJ2FN0GZLe31PUQvE0k/Ap9Buabcnt5Ftq3EhuJb/Xz4AzRukce2w3zV3T45bjtEylsxl2XP/auF/vQ3SLwolzqIHAYlaVmPIHkPqRXtC12wGoKJL+GFO4I45G4cuSNt6hTfSJXFds1OixRW9lezcXE73crA+mcf6GiDXKEkZ3G9c2Xt3JZ2iWNtp8bBQe8lllOWJJJOAKt6P2h1DWtTVEhhjypaTgyFRQPnuTgUJ4J1bJ4s0HLag/qcokuMtuByoTcTMwKLnFFBIjsySqBKOmeftVaSJY8s2DmkzSiA3tJXbIDAelW7ZXgKkg7VZW7iQ+IdeVW0kgnTw4qbk2uSXCGJcB2U8OCDkHG9XVujIyxpvIxAUDqaHXNzBbRkuVTA3LEAUY0mLT7XUrJ4dStb95v4ncSK6xMGU4GD9aMMblz6F8uSMeH2VYJmU96F/FVnjx67itNDEb3SuPmkikL89xQ3ULKOG8vwg2Sbjx7/wDyj2hyK9pLAuPw5DjHQHcfQirIx5aFJS4sxd3ZNDIkgOQ64PuK0GjxL/01T+aMlfl0od2k722uJVAyiOHH8ppNDuZJLhoc7OuMeooe6JPlWEtVnBtkYDJQ4aspq7otyJovDIuGrbRWyyh45B8Qxis3qumBy6j4lG3riuX2D3QGvb2M36XUa4S5XxAfqogmtqEAnXikAwW8/KhkFkLi2urMn8WL8WI+nWmQyoYlyBnG+ak6OQNnu4Vn1F7i4UyORHHjfwqOftk/Sh519rexgsrVFWKNSXLLkyOc5NAGkPU5qMtk1pLDFGa8smFrvWJm06WyRgsMxXjVVxkA5G9DDJwOeY255qJjkikk+KrFFLog5Njidl36CtT2DuDFe3K55oN6yh3IFHeyEjJczuOoAqnU/wA2MaX+qNhfzNkOhwwOxqnPqErAd4MbY260lxMM8+tVJZAayoxNtkct3GdmJpIr51YLEHqCTBY1NbjLCrqVFLbbK3aO4cWSrK3FJI4AHkOdZhneN1eNmRsYypwaJ9pZuO6WMH4Bv7mhkxyF9hWhp41jRlaqe7Kza9lu1o0m2ki1COe6SUABu84iuPetv2U7Zdn1uykt28CyRKD38ZVQwyOfLlj9q42z93BGfWnq550Xhjdlayyqj6E1Vba+SOWGWKWGdGQSIQwPUb/vWZ02Rba7jfIBU7/KuY2Gr3unn/CXMkQJDMoOxPng7Vu9FhvL7S4tSk4T3rElFGMDOM4pLPicPIcwZN/ibu4lAl7yPqOIYoJq5lFyJFGA65U+tG7K249Oik6r4T7U+7skuLBlx4o9waq2snuRzO8upLWdLqMENGfEPNetUbiGdpneEZjY8S/PetNqtkjxOeEZ6+x50Eh1GSyjW2MQfu9gfTpRTOaOfGmGlyaaTWuZYvlSS/EK8DSOcke9A4XOGxRrsyeAzUEPx0d0RO7i4/OqdR+lDWlX5EwvK5I51UeTOxqRmzUZG9Z1Gq3Y1d+W9XIcIuTyFV4wB03p0rFIHPQDNSXPBFulZmNUfvb24fORx7fLaq8n+X7UshJUk8ySTTX/AMqtSKpJGJJ22y1NvCB5b0kbbV6U7Y6U1eVEBYVs7DrXbNAhFnplrAvJIlHzriline3kEX65FX9yK7hbsAox5UhrH0h/Qx7YUtruSBWRMcBG6kVctpllyoPxbMpP7UIDcsVV1NDPaSxrLLEXUrxxSFGHsRSsZ01Y1PEmnXYC7Szx6e00dzcxxSZyFZsE+gHWse+v2XEcl2PmFrL6vb3NnqM0N4xeZTu5JPGOhyarK21aENPCrszJ55p1RIaaaVudeNNFAlI3T3r3SvNzHvXHCtsc1oNAIeEKeams+9F+zZPfyDPlVOdeDGNLKsiD7Q8Qpn3bFX0GQM+VS8ChMgDNZrZtbUwdHbk9Kp66fu9gw/M21GUrO9rGINuoPh3OKlh8siRVqPHE2Z1/h9qbJ8EZ8qU/AaST+EtayMIlY5Pyrw5ikpRzFAIV7OR9/rlquOThv23rrtvJXKuxYzryZ6Rtj6V063NZesfmjW0MfxthJW2qG4k8JFeUnFV7k0rY3Rzft/bDvY7lRuPCT5g8qyQIxW87bgGykz0GRWBHKtfSu8Zj62O3Lwf/2Q==';
        const fileName = 'example.png'; // 指定要下载的文件名
        downloadBase64File(contentBase64, fileName); // 调用函数下载文件

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://tool.chinaz.com/tools/imgtobase
This website can convert images to base64 format